# Parse Consolidated Log Data

Tags: monitoring

Our custom applications are sending their log data to a SQL table. I am looking for a piece of software that will allow me to configure a rule engine to parse this data and look for certain patters that I will configure. For example I want to raise an alert when a certain event doesn't happen for more than x minutes, or a certain event doesn't succeed for more than y minutes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this kind of things (and more) with [Octopussy](http://www.8pussy.org) project. (disclaimer: it's my project)

You can also take a look at [syslog.org](http://syslog.org/) website for other logging solutions.